Multiple make Rules without targets or prerequisites
I might have the terminology wrong so feel free to correct me. We have been abusing make for sometime to do a lot of our builds. 99% of the time this is using phony targets. We have docker build projects where we call docker build for each of the versioned docker files. The file structure would look something like this:
6/Dockerfile
8/Dockerfile

Getting the list of docker files in the project is easy.
DOCKERFILES:=$(wildcard */Dockerfile)

Currently we are using this approach to build the docker files:
.PHONY: all
all: lint init build-images
.PHONY: lint
lint:
    $(foreach image, $(DOCKERFILES),$(call dockerLint,$(image),$(_DOCKER_BUILD_ARCH)))

.PHONY: init
init:
    $(foreach image, $(DOCKERFILES),$(call initVariablesForImage,$(image)))

.PHONY: build-images
build-images:
    $(foreach image, $(DOCKERFILES),$(call dockerBuildPush,$(image),$(_DOCKER_BUILD_ARCH)))

However in the interest of trying to better understand make and avoid the foreach is it possible to define multiple rules that match the Dockerfile and run the relevant recipes? I have had some success with a single rule but as soon as I try and do multiple recipes it falls over.
.PHONY: test
test: $(DOCKERFILES)

$(DOCKERFILES):*
    $(info ***** build $@)

Which gives the following output:
***** build 6/Dockerfile
***** build 8/Dockerfile

I expect that this approach is wrong based on when I try to introduce other targets I get override warnings or circular references:
warning: overriding commands for target `8/Dockerfile'
warning: ignoring old commands for target `8/Dockerfile'

...

make: Circular 6/Dockerfile <- 6/Dockerfile dependency dropped.
make: Circular 7/Dockerfile <- 7/Dockerfile dependency dropped.
make: Circular 8/Dockerfile <- 8/Dockerfile dependency dropped.

I wanted to stop and pause and see if what I want to achieve is even possible. What we have works but it would be nice to explore alternatives to see if we can come up with cleaner implementations.

Are there dependencies between the lint, init and build steps? For a given docker file, say 6/Dockerfile, and for each of the 3 steps, what are the inputs (the files that are used by the recipe) and the products (the files that are created/updates by the recipe)?

@RenaudPacalet - Linting is static code analysis and can be done in isolation as is not needed for the other steps. The init builds up variables that are needed for the build and other steps that I left out for simplification. With docker builds there are no outputs because the images are pushed to the docker registry so there is only the input docker file. With the linting though there is an output file which is generated although this is the final output and is not used in any additional steps.

Usually when you write a recipe that loops over a number of builds there are chances that you can do much better by letting make handle all builds separately. Example with static pattern rules:
DOCKERFILES := $(wildcard */Dockerfile)
LINTS := $(addprefix lint-,$(DOCKERFILES))
INITS := $(addprefix init-,$(DOCKERFILES))
BUILDS := $(addprefix build-images-,$(DOCKERFILES))

.PHONY: all lint init build-images $(LINTS) $(INITS) $(BUILDS)

all: lint init build-images

lint: $(LINTS)

$(LINTS): lint-%: %
    $(call dockerLint,$<,$(_DOCKER_BUILD_ARCH))

init: $(INITS)

$(INITS): init-%: %
    $(call initVariablesForImage,$<)

build-images: $(BUILDS)

$(BUILDS): build-images-%: %
    $(call dockerBuildPush,$<,$(_DOCKER_BUILD_ARCH))

One of the advantages is that make can run recipes in parallel, while loops in recipes are sequential. Try make -j12 if you have 12 cores and see...
Warning: if there are dependencies between the lint, init and build steps they should be specified. Your question does not contain enough information to suggest a solution but if lint shall run before init and init before build, you could adapt the static pattern rules for init and build:
$(INITS): init-%: % lint-%
    $(call initVariablesForImage,$<)

$(BUILDS): build-images-%: % init-%
    $(call dockerBuildPush,$<,$(_DOCKER_BUILD_ARCH))

Important: as we are using only phony targets everything is rebuilt each time we run make all. But make can do better if it knows the inputs (the files that are used by the recipe) and the products (the files that are created or updated by the recipe) of each rule. With all this make can compare the last modification dates of inputs and products to decide if a recipe must be run or if running it is useless because the products are up to date with respect to the inputs. Your question does not contain enough information to suggest a solution.

This worked great, my only issue was copy pasting from slack which inserted spaces instead of a tab . I am able to build on what you have provided to work with the other steps I mentioned.

Tabs are not rendered properly on SO and their use is not recommended: Also, use spaces instead of tabs, as tabs usually are not correctly formatted on Stack Overflow, particularly for indenting. So most posts in the makefile tag use spaces instead of tabs and you need to replace them with tabs yourself when you copy-paste.
